# I couldn't find reason behind garbage values here in this code

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std;

class Base {

private: int b;

protected: int a;

public: int c; void setdata(); int getdata(); };

void Base ::setdata() { int a = 10; int b = 20; int c = 30; }

int Base::getdata() { return b; }

class Derived: public Base { public: void display() { setdata(); cout << a << endl << getdata() << endl << c << endl; } };

int main() { Derived xyz; xyz.display(); return 0; }
```

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: This should have a constructor to set up safe defaults.

Comment: What is you question? "I cant find a reson" is a problem, not a _question_. Anyway  there is no garbage value visible in your code! Please see (and apply) hints given in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in our [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 4):

Lets look at your `setdata` function:

```
void Base ::setdata() { int a = 10; int b = 20; int c = 30; }
```

Inside it you define three new variables `a`, `b` and `c`, which are totally unrelated with the `Base` member variables of the same name.

That means the `Base` member variables will be uninitialized and with *indeterminate* values. And printing them leads to *undefined behavior*.

Your `setdata` function should set the `Base` member variables, which are already declared and defined and can be used as-is:

```
void Base ::setdata() { a = 10; b = 20; c = 30; }
```

---

With that said, a better solution is to use a *constructor* to initialize the member variables instead of a separate function:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base()
        : a{ 10 }, b{ 20 }, c{ 30 }  // An initializer list, to initialize members
    {
        // Empty body of constructor function
    }

    // Rest of class, without the setdata function ...
};
```